# How do I localize Text in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to localize text in my Xamarin Forms project for Android.

I set up a new project as a testing environment, following [this](https://lokalise.com/blog/xamarin-forms-internationalization/) tutorial, however the language of the text doesn´t change when I press the button.
The Lang.resx (standard is german) file is set public, the Lang.en.resx file is set to no code generated. Both files have the same keys (switch-de, switch-en, welcome).

I tried to close and reopen the App after changing the language and I disabled fast deployment, neither fixed the problem. The Text stays german.

This is the SwitchPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace I18nTest
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SwitchPage : ContentPage
    {
        public SwitchPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(100),

                Children =
                {
                    welcomeLabel,
                    switchENButton,
                    switchDEButton
                }
            };
        }

        Label welcomeLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = Language.Lang.welcome,
            Margin = new Thickness(100, 100, 100, 50),
            FontSize = 80,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
        };
        Button switchENButton = new Button
        {
            Text = Language.Lang.switch_en,
        };
        Button switchDEButton = new Button
        {
            Text = Language.Lang.switch_de,
        };


        private void Button_de_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de", false);
        }

        private async void Button_en_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en", false);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the SwitchPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="I18nTest.SwitchPage"
             xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:i18nMalWieder.Language">

    <StackLayout>
    <Label Text="{x:Static resources:Lang.welcome}" FontSize="Header" Margin="100,100,100,50" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
    <Button Text="{x:Static resources:Lang.switch_de}" Clicked="Button_de_Clicked" HeightRequest="100"/>
    <Button Text="{x:Static resources:Lang.switch_en}" Clicked="Button_en_Clicked" HeightRequest="100"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Xamarin's documentation on localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows) says that using CurrentUICulture might not be ideal for that:

> Testing localization is best accomplished by changing your device
> language. It is possible to set the value of
> System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture in code but behavior
> is inconsistent across platforms so this is not recommended for
> testing.

Your implementation might be working just fine; however changing the language pragmatically might not behave the same way as changing the device language from the phone's settings.

Comment: I changed the system language and it worked right away. Thanks a lot!